# Unable to get access to libextern_draco.so file for compression

Tags: compression, blender

I have been trying to convert fbx into gltf and using the draco compression.
It gives me in a log saying that
`libextern_draco.so exists at a provided location and draco mesh compression is available`

but later it throws error

```
12:46:21 | INFO: Primitives created: 1
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/__init__.py", line 637, in execute
return gltf2_blender_export.save(context, export_settings)
File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_export.py", line 46, in save
json, buffer = __export(export_settings)
File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender   /exp/gltf2_blender_export.py", line 63, in __export
__gather_gltf(exporter, export_settings)
File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_export.py", line 80, in __gather_gltf
gltf2_io_draco_compression_extension.encode_scene_primitives(scenes, export_settings)
File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/io/exp/gltf2_io_draco_compression_extension.py", line 30, in encode_scene_primitives
dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(str(dll_path().resolve()))
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /app/lib/libextern_draco.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

location: /usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:132
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: also reported here https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/627

Comment: sounds like, it might be a problem with a specific release of blender, maybe try an older version? Its hard to suggest which once had a specific release of a python embedded that would work. if the installation includes this `libextern_draco.so` file, thats a good sign